# How to use a check_box_tag to create or destroy a has_many-trough association in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, checkbox, associations

In my Rails application, I have a campaign that belongs to a company. The company has many groups and one or more of those groups can be connected to the campaign trough a model called `:general_connections`.

For this campaign I'm trying to show a list of groups (with checkboxes) for the associated company. By checking a box, a `:general_connection` should be created and by unchecking it, this specific `:general_connection` should be `destroyed`.

Models:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :campaigns
  has_many :groups
end

class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :general_connections
  has_many :groups, through: :general_connections
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :general_connections
  has_many :campaigns, through: :general_connections
end

class GeneralConnection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :campaign
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :company
end
```

Controllers:

```
#campaign_controller.rb /show
  def show
      @campaign = Campaign.find(params[:id])
    @company = Company.find(current_user.current_company)
    @main_groups = @company.groups
    @general_connections = @campaign.general_connections
    @groups = @campaign.groups
  end

#general_connection_controller.rb /connect_group_to_campaign
  def connect_group_to_campaign
    group = group.find(params[:group_id])
    @campaign = Campaign.find(params[:id])
    @campaign.general_connections.create(group: group)

    redirect_to :back
  end

#general_connection_controller.rb /disconnect_group_from_campaign
  def disconnect_group_from_campaign
    @general_connection = GeneralConnection.where("group_id = ? AND campaign_id = ?", params[:group_id], @campaign.id).first
    group = @general_connection.oneliner

    @general_connection.destroy

    redirect_to :back
  end
```

View with form_tag:

```
        <h5>Groups for this campaign</h5>
        <div class="row">
            <% @main_groups.each do |group| %>
                <%= form_tag connect_group_to_campaign_path do |f| %>
                <%= hidden_field_tag 'campaign_id', @campaign.id %>
                  <%= f.check_box_tag group.id, group.id, true %>
                <% end %>

                <%= form_tag disconnect_group_from_campaign_path do |f| %>
                <%= hidden_field_tag 'campaign_id', @campaign.id %>
                  <%= f.check_box_tag group.id, group.id, false %>
                <% end %>

            <% end %>
        </div>
```

I believe that my attempt in the `View` is probably rubbish, but I just wanted to first try it out myself.

My questions are:

1. Is this even possible?
2. And if so, how can I compose this?

**Update:**
Did a test with @Jeff's answer:

```
<%= form_for @campaign do |f| %>
<div class="form-group">
    <ul>
        <% @main_groups.each do |group| %>  
            <li>
            <%= check_box_tag :group_id, group.id, @campaign.general_connections.include?(group) %>
            <%= group.title %>
            </li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>   
</div>
<div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Save groups", class: "btn waves-effect waves-light" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

But no `checkboxes` are showing and I'm not sure how this adds a line to my `general_connections table`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently finished a feature very similar to what you describe. The code here proved successful for me, although it likely needs significant adjusting for your needs:

```
<%= form_for(@assignment) do |a| %>

  <%= a.label :name %>
  <%= a.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= a.label :possible, "Points Possible" %>
  <%= a.text_field :possible, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= a.label :priority %>
  <%= a.select(:priority, [0,1,2,3], :selected =>[2]) %>

  <% Assignment.each do |assignment| %>
     <%= check_box_tag :preassign_ids, assignment.id, 
          @assignment.preconditions.include?(assignment), :name => 'assignment[preassign_ids][]' %>
     <%= assignment.name %>
  <% end %>

  <%= a.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
 <% end %>
```

This example uses two models: first, "Assignments"; second, a join model called, "Preconditions" that creates relationships between the assignments. The Preconditions table includes two columns: "mainassign" and "preassign." So that's where :preassign_ids comes into play. You'll need to do some similar work with the associations in your app.

In this code, clicking a checkbox create a precondition that links the current assignment to another assignment. I haven't yet tested whether relationships are destroyed by unclicking the checkboxes, but the first part is working perfectly.

I'm fairly new myself, so I don't know if code from my other files would be helpful. I'm happy to post more if you think this approach is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Jeff. I tried to convert it. It's not giving me any errors, but also isn't showing me a `checkbox`. I don't see you use any type of `form method` (`form_tag` or `form_for`): how do you `submit` it then?

Comment: I added the rest of the code, including the form header and submit button, in case that helps. If you're not seeing checkboxes, there are a dozen possible reasons. The first that comes to mind is that you don't yet have any companies in your development database.

Comment: Thanks again @Jeff. I updated my question with a test of your solution: it still doesn't show 'checkboxes'. The company doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: Your code looks like it should show a checkbox for each record that is included in @main_groups. From your controllers, I'm assuming this form is loaded with the show action of the campaign controller. So that should be one check for each group associated with the user's current company. Have you tried using the rails console to make sure the company in question has some groups?

Also, I think the :group_id needs to be plural. i.e. "check_box_tag :group_ids" because it includes all of the group_ids that are included in the general_connections for that campaign.